# Convert CURL command line to Python script

Tags: python, curl

Having way too much trouble making this CMD line curl statement work in python script...help!  Attempting to use `Urllib`.

```
curl -X POST "http://api.postmarkapp.com/email" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Postmark-Server-Token: abcdef-1234-46cc-b2ab-38e3a208ab2b" \
-v \
-d "{From: 'sender@email.com', To: 'recipient@email.com', Subject: 'Postmark test', HtmlBody: '<html><body><strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.</body></html>'}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok so you should probably user urllib2 to submit the actual request but here is the code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = "http://api.postmarkapp.com/email"
data = "{From: 'sender@email.com', To: 'recipient@email.com', Subject:   'Postmark test', HtmlBody: 'Hello dear Postmark user.'}"
headers = { "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Conthent-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Postmark-Server-Token": "abcdef-1234-46cc-b2ab-38e3a208ab2b"}
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Check out: [urllib2 the unwritten manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)

I get a 401 unauthorized response so I guess it works :)